# How to detect Bluetooth crash or shutdown with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm try to communicate with a Bluetooth Low Energy device with de QtBluetooth.dll. So, I've made an application that list every BLE devices, connect to it, read write and notify values and, finally, disconnect.

I listen to all state changement with the [connect()](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) function of Qt ; using SIGNALS/SLOTS system.

```
controller = new QLowEnergyController(currentDevice.getDevice());
    connect(controller, &QLowEnergyController::connected,
            this, &Device::deviceConnected);
    connect(controller, &QLowEnergyController::disconnected,
        this, &Device::deviceDisconnected);
    connect(controller, &QLowEnergyController::discoveryFinished,
        this, &Device::serviceScanDone);
    connect(controller, QOverload<QLowEnergyController::Error>::of(&QLowEnergyController::error),
            this, &Device::errorReceived);
    connect(controller, &QLowEnergyController::serviceDiscovered,
            this, &Device::addLowEnergyService);
    connect(controller, &QLowEnergyController::stateChanged,
            this, &Device::deviceStateChanged);
```

That's works fine but there is a problem. When my device suddenly shutdown, I have absolutly no way to get the "crash" or the shutdown of my device. Even the "stateChanged" event of my controller object doesn't throw any state.

So how can I retrieve the crash when it comes up ? Is there an event listener I am missing ?

Thanks for your help !

[EDIT]

I've made a QThread to handle error and, even when I shut down my device, the qInfo() say this :

```
QLowEnergyController::Error(NoError)
QLowEnergyController::ControllerState(DiscoveredState)
```

the QThread :

```
QThread * errorThread = QThread::create([this]() {
        while (this->controller->error() != QLowEnergyController::NetworkError)
        {
            qInfo() << this->controller->error();
            qInfo() << this->controller->state();
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        qInfo() << this->controller->error();
        qInfo() << this->controller->state();
    });
    errorThread->start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Which Qt version are you using? Since Qt 5.10, there is an error type `QLowEnergyController::RemoteHostClosedError`:

> The remote device closed the connection. This value was introduced by Qt 5.10.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlowenergycontroller.html#Error-enum for further information.
This error will be emitted via the `error`-signal.

In earlier versions as well, I am pretty sure that you will receive a `QLowEnergyController::NetworkError` when reading from or writing to a crashed device.

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.11, but the error listener never changes.

Comment: Just to be sure: Can you check the return value of the `connect`? Is the connection successful?

Comment: All my connects are "true"

Answer (score 0):

Considering Qt supports BLE on Mac, iOS, Android and Windows 10, the only reliable way to tell if your connections are still alive is to peridocally do I/O with them and see if your Connection- or Serviceobjects signal an error or not. If you're exclusively using BLE/4.1 I'd suggest to request a read on the smallest gatt attribute, most devices have a 'battery' service that you're bound to check periodically anyway.